# promise.all to use getDownloadURL() in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, asynchronous, promise, firebase-storage

I'm struggling to fetch the download image URL in firebase storage.

What I wanted to achieve with this code is to upload two images one after another and to push the image URL to the array.

However, my code doesn't work correctly as asynchronous. 
Ther result after Promise.all() suppose to return the array with URL.
I'll appreciate if someone guides me to solve this issue.

```
const handleUpload = () => {
    Promise.all([uploadImage(window1Image), uploadImage(window2Image)])
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

const uploadImage = (image) => {
    const uuid = Date.now() + uuidv4();
    const imageToServer = storage.ref(`images/${uuid}`).put(image);
    imageToServer.on(
      'state_changed',
      (snapshot) => {
        const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
      },
      () => {
        storage
          .ref('images')
          .child(uuid)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((data) => data);
      },
    );
  };
```

Comment: It's probably because you didn't set `Promise.all` to be returned.

Comment: I think you need to return `imageToServer`(Promise) from `uploadImage` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`then()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask#then) method of [`UploadTask`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.UploadTask) which "behaves **like a Promise**, and resolves with its snapshot data when the upload completes".

The following should work (untested):

```
  const handleUpload = () => {
    Promise.all([uploadImage(window1Image), uploadImage(window2Image)])
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  const uploadImage = image => {
    const uuid = Date.now() + uuidv4();
    const imageToServer = storage.ref(`images/${uuid}`).put(image);
    return imageToServer.then(uploadTaskSnapshot => {
      return uploadTaskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    });
  };
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your solution.
You are right. this code works perfectly!